# Apple B2B App Store - Few Doubts

Tags: ios, app-store, b2b

I have read about Apple B2B on Apple, Google, here and everywhere, but there are few questions I cannot get answers to. Here they are:

1. Is it mandatory that a B2B app should have a sign-up functionality?
   Our application have login functionality for a a specific business
   but no sign-up functionality.
2. We want the app to be downloadable by a one or two specific business, is
   this be achievable via B2B App Store?

Our application do not have sign-up and but users have to login in using the specific credentials provided to them by their business. So can we deploy such app on B2B apps Store?

Comment: You can deploy apps with only a sign-in and no in-app registration on the standard app store, so I can't see a problem with making it available via B2B.  B2B isn't an app-store per-se, rather you make your app available to specific enterprise customers through iTunes Connect - https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/

Comment: @Paulw11 But without providing the sign-up functionality we are restricting users from using the app; as without sign-in the app is completely unusable. Which Apple do not allow on Standard App Store, I believe they reject such apps. Correct?

Comment: No.  As long as you provide an account for testing when you submit for approval it is ok. For example, download Go Reception for iPad

Comment: @Paulw11 Great! Thanks a lot!... We will give the standard account a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any kind of the requirement mentation into the guide line.

In my case one of the application developed for B2B in that app not included registration  flow then app is live on B2B Store.

For Point 1

> Question about new user in my application admin has a role for create new user from website and those users can
>   login and visit the all functionality bases on the privileges
>   assign into the admin panel.

For Point 2

> Purchase the custom B2B app through the program website. The developer
>   you’re working with should notify you when the app is available for
>   purchase. After you've been notified, log in to the Volume Purchase
>   Program website to see the custom B2B apps that have been created for
>   your business. Custom B2B apps are available only to the businesses
>   specified by the developer and are not visible to other businesses in
>   the program.

[Official guideline document for  Purchase
Program for B2B.](http://images.apple.com/business/docs/ASVPP_Business_Guide_US.pdf)

Comment: Thanks that explains well ... Thanks. We now have two options one from Paulw11 and other by you. Thanks again guys. We will post our feedback for this once its its deployed with either of the way.